# solve the outgoing signal problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the outgoing signal problem, 
$u_{tt} - c^2 u_{xx}, x>0$

$u_x(0,t) = s(t) $

Where $s(t)$ is a known signal.  Hint: look for a right-traveling wave.

So I am quite confused here because you can't use D'Ambert's formula since your only initial condition is a $x$ derivative of $u$ and to use that you need an $x$ derivative and an initial condition and I have neither. I have tried to go about the derivation for D'Ambert's and see if that gives me anything useful, but it doesn't seem to yield anything...
What I did was,

$u(t,x) = p(x-ct) + q(x+ct)$

$u_x(t,x) = p'(x-ct) + q'(x+ct)$

$u(t,0) = p(-ct) + q(ct)$

Let $S'(t) = s(t)$

$u_x(t,0) = p'(-ct) + q'(ct) = S'(t)$

$p(-ct) + q(ct) = S(t)$

But then you can't really get any form on S(t) because everything just cancels...

Does anyone have any idea how I can solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The condition $u_x(0,t)=s(t)$ isn't sufficient to determine the functions $p$ and $q$.

$u(t,x) = p(x-ct) + q(x+ct)$

$u_x(t,x) = p'(x-ct) + q'(x+ct)$

$$u_x(0,t) = p'(-ct) + q'(ct)=s(t)$$
$$-\frac{1}{c}p(-ct)+\frac{1}{c}q(ct)=\int_0^t s(\theta)d\theta+\text{constant}$$
First particular solution with $T=ct$ 
$$-\frac{1}{c}p(-T)+\frac{1}{c}q(T)=\int_0^{T/c} s(\theta)d\theta+\text{constant}$$
$$\begin{cases}
p(-T)=0\\
q(T)=c\int_0^{T/c} s(\theta)d\theta+\text{constant}
\end{cases}$$
$$T=x+ct\quad\to\quad u_1(x,t)=c\int_0^{\frac{x+ct}{c}} s(\theta)d\theta+\text{constant}$$
Second particular solution with $T=-ct$ 
$$-\frac{1}{c}p(T)+\frac{1}{c}q(-T)=\int_0^{-T/c} s(\theta)d\theta+\text{constant}$$
$$\begin{cases}
q(-T)=0\\
p(T)=-c\int_0^{-T/c} s(\theta)d\theta+\text{constant}
\end{cases}$$
$$T=x-ct\quad\to\quad u_2(x,t)=-c\int_0^{\frac{-x+ct}{c}} s(\theta)d\theta+\text{constant}$$
General solution : $u(x,t)=c_1u_1+c_2u_2=c_1c\int_0^{\frac{x+ct}{c}} s(\theta)d\theta-c_2c\int_0^{\frac{-x+ct}{c}} s(\theta)d\theta+\text{constant}$

$u_x(x,t)=c_1 s\left(\frac{x+ct}{c}\right) +c_2s\left(\frac{-x+ct}{c}\right)$

In order to satisfy $u_x(0,t)=s(t) \quad\to\quad c_1+c_2=1$

$u(x,t)= (\frac{1}{2}+C_1)c\int_0^{\frac{x+ct}{c}} s(\theta)d\theta-(\frac{1}{2}-C_1)c\int_0^{\frac{-x+ct}{c}} s(\theta)d\theta+C_2$

An initial condition is probably missing to determine the constants $C_1=C_2=0$ so that :
$$u(x,t)= \frac{c}{2}\left(\int_0^{\frac{x+ct}{c}} s(\theta)d\theta-\int_0^{\frac{-x+ct}{c}} s(\theta)d\theta\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

The initial condition is $u_x(0,t) = s(t)$ not $u(0,t) = s(t)$. Thanks for pointing out the mistake in the calculus. From that I get that,

$u(0,t) = p(-ct) + q(ct)$

+

$c * \bigg( S(t) = -\frac{1}{c}p(-ct) + \frac{1}{c}q(ct) \bigg)$

$=$

$u(0,t) + cS(t) = 2q(ct)$

$\frac{1}{2} u(0,t) + \frac{1}{2c}S(t) = q(ct)$

But from here I am not sure what to do?